# How to expose custom functions to angularjs expressions

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a function, inArray that i would like/need to expose to the angularjs epressions:

The function

```
function inArray( needle, haystack, assocKey ){
    assocKey = assocKey || false;
    for(var i=0;i<haystack.length;++i){
        if( assocKey ){
            if( haystack[i][assocKey] == needle ){
                return true;
            }
        } else if( haystack[i] == needle ){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

The html in question

```
<div ng-show="inArray(currentUser.id, item.comments, 'commenter_id')">
   You have commented on this already.
</div>
```

Where a simplified item example would be:

```
item = {
  post: 'sfdcsdvsdv',
  images: ['1.png','2.png'],
  date: 'some date',
  comments:[{ 
      commenter_id: 321654987,
      comment: 'sdfvsdvsdfv',
      date: 'some other date'
    },{ 
      commenter_id: 65498721,
      comment: 'ptyopoinmu',
      date: 'some other date'
  }]
}
```

This code doesn't even touch the inArray function, which i have created in the global namespace.

I assume this is for safety, ie preventing bad html running dodgy functions the user doesn't want to run, but is there a way of allowing set functions through?

### ----------

**A working answer**
Using the @Martin answer below i was able to put together a working solution:

The filter

```
angular.module('myApp').filter('inArray',  function() { // register new filter
    return function( input, needle, assocKey ){ // filter arguments
        return inArray( input, needle, assocKey ); // implementation
    }
});
```

The html

```
<div ng-show="item.comments | inArray:currentUser.id:'commenter_id'">
    You have already commented on this
</div>
```

Comment: you need to assign the inArray() to $scope

Comment: thnx @jrath, however i have an issue with this answer though, please see matthiasgiger's answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use filters to promote code reuse. Attaching it to the scope or rootScope is a bad smell. With your function in your example you can do

```
angular.module('app').filter('inArray',  function() { return inArray });
```

Then in your view

```
<div ng-show="currentUser.id | inArray : item.comments : 'commenter_id'">
    You have commented on this already. 
</div>
```

That said, you probably want to reverse the order of haystack and needle parameters to fit the idiom better.

Comment: i'm not sure i completely follow here, how is the filter inArray being passed to the expression?

Comment: It is being passed by registering it as a filter in Angular's Inversion of Control container. Any filter is available in any expression.

Comment: After searching i cannot find anything on the ¦ character. I dug around on filters and put together a filter but with the expression: `<div ng-show="item.comments | inArray:currentUser.id:'ommenter_id'">`  This works. I did find some more docs on expressions @  http://teropa.info/blog/2014/03/23/angularjs-expressions-cheatsheet.html

Comment: damn you changed the post, i was kind of hoping there was a new operator i could us haha!

Comment: Sorry. The keyboard on my phone is not so great for writing code.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to add it to the Angular-scope:

```
$scope.inArray = function( needle, haystack, assocKey ){ .. }
```

This way Angular will know the inArray function.

Everything on the $scope object can directly be accessed from the HTML-Code.

Comment: Yes, but in this instance, i have a partial being recycled in many parts of the app, currently 6 locations, using 3 different controllers. It seems quite verbose to have to add this function to every controller. Is it possible to somehow add this to a global scope somewhere?

Comment: @John use $rootScope instead of $scope for it to be global (or maybe you can use a service: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services)

Comment: But how, it is best to create an arbitary service to manipulate the $rootScope?

Comment: @MazzCris, using `$rootScope` is not a good approach. OP should use a service/factory to achieve that

Comment: Yep. Don't use $rootScope. Like @Vineet says use service/factory and inject it to controllers which need it.

Comment: Even if I proposed both the approaches, I agree with @Vineet and Sharko